# jQuery mobile adds additional scrollbar to page

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, scrollbar

I’m currently working with jQuery mobile (for the first time).
One of my pages contains a very long text. If I view this page on a desktop browser, jquery will add scroll-bar to the page (additional to the one of the browser).
How can I remove the second scroll bar?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Header</title>
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
...
</head>
<body>
<div id="infoPage" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" data-fullscreen="false" id="detailsHeader">
        <a href="../index.html" rel="external" data-icon="back" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        <h1>Information</h1>
        <a href="javascript:history.go(0)" data-icon="refresh" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn-right">Refresh</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">

        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
            <h1>Information</h1>

            <table  data-role="table" data-mode="reflow">
              ....
            </table>
        </div>

       <div data-role="content">
           <pre>...large text goes here....</pre>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" data-fullscreen="false" id="detailsFooter">
        <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#overview" rel="external" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="top">Status</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="top" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Info</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry... I have completely forgotten the code.

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Comment: I’ve added the code to the question

Answer (score 0):

I had a double scrollbar when I was using a panel.  I had to switch my CSS references from this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.2.css">
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css">
```

Otherwise try removing every div from your page and add them back one by one until you see which one is causing the second scroll bar.